# How do I find the average of top list items?

Tags: calculus, average

Here's the situation:

I have a lot of "top lists" like so:

list1:

1. iPhone 6
2. Galaxy S5
3. LG G4

list2:

1. Galaxy S5
2. OnePlus One
3. iPhone 6
4. LG G4
5. Nexus 5

list3:

1. LG G4
2. Galaxy S5
3. Nexus 5

And so on...

They are all different in length and order.

I need to generate a new top list which should show an average of all those items. "A top of the tops".
How do I do that? I thought that the easiest way would be just to calculate straight averages of each item (e.g.Galaxy S5).

But what should I do with those items which appears just in some lists but not all?
I can't calculate straight averages if item is present only in few lists because that won't be fair...

Comment: You could calculate a straight average of the lists every item _does_ appear on. For instance, the iPhone 6 appears in first place in one list and third place in another, so it has an "average" of second place. The Galaxy S5, on the other hand, has two second places and one first place, which averages to a $1.67$th place. And so on.

Comment: Can you define what "straight averages" are ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is hard to answer because you don't really define the meaning of "fair" when combining rankings. As @SteveKass comments, there is no right way. Preferential voting schemes try to find a reasonable solution. The wikipedia discussion at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferential_voting offers some ideas.

Here's one you might try. Give each item a score of 10, 9, 8, ... when it is at rank 1, 2, 3, ... on one of your top 10 lists. Then just sum the scores, and rank the items accordingly. (This is essentially @WillFisher 's answer.)

With that algorithm an item not on a list scores 0 for that list. That would allow for bullet balloting: someone who really liked phone X would choose not to give a second or third choice. (See http://electology.org/bullet-voting .)

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would just be for each item, sum up their rankings. Then order them in ascending order of that sum. Or if you want different categories to be weighted differently, then multiply each rank in that category by a scalar when summing to give different weight to different categories. The ones with shorter lengths could be used as tie breakers between those phones.
Just the plain summing and ordering will have the same effect as just averaging their ranking, and apply weight to different categories has the same effect as just taking a weighted average.

Comment: Maybe the average for phone $X$ should include a “dummy rank” for each list not containing $X$. (This could be rank $n+1$ for a list of $n$ items.) Otherwise, a phone that is ranked #1 on just one list, but is not ranked at all in any other list, would have a higher rating than a phone that is ranked #1 on 10 lists and #2 on 5 lists. There is no “right” way to do this, and you should make up examples that test whether the result you’re getting is reasonable. And you should change the examples slightly to be sure small changes in the input don’t cause big changes in the output.

Comment: Yes! That's the problem!
I thought about this "dummy rank" as well. But then you need to add that dummy ranked item to the n, so that the next dummy item is lower?

Comment: The sum of ranks can be a very poor estimate. Let an item appear in the first place of five lists, and another item appear in the fourth position of a single list. You have $5>4$ !

Comment: Another solution, is on the lists with less, make the highest ranked gain negative points to help it.